# It's possible to add a JTextField to a JLabel?

Tags: java, jlabel, jtextfield

So,I have a JLabel and a JTextField,it's there a possible way to add the JTextField to JLabel,can you give me some examples? I know there are lots of alternatives but I want to do it this way.

```
JTextField text=new JTextField();
text.setText("this is textfield");
text.setBounds(20,0,100,20);
//now the jlabel
JLabel label=new JLabel();
label.setOpaque(true);
label.setBackground(Color.blue);
label.add(text);//this is what I tryed
```

Comment: You probably want to use `JPanel`.

Comment: Based on JLabel constructors/methods, my answer would be no. Just use JPanel as "Murat K." suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a JPanel instead of a JLabel. If you are up to create a GUI it is the easiest way, to cut everything into smaller panels you can finaly join.

```
JTextField text=new JTextField();
text.setText("this is textfield");
text.setBounds(20,0,100,20);
JPanel panel=new JPanel();
panel.addLayout(new FlowLayout());
panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
panel.add(text);
```

this should work fine I hope

Comment: Don't use setBounds(). The layout manager, in this case FlowLayout, with determine the size and location of the text field within the panel. Also when you create the text field use `new JTextField(10)`, so the text field can return a preferred size of the text field.